# How to install Pylance and Python in vscode, without letting it change basic mouse click actions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Vscode for my python project. I liked the features such as autocompletion, and docstrings provided by the extensions Pylance and Python. However, I find it annoying that if we install these packages the mouse right-click menu is altered and also the mouse right-click behaviours action is also changed.

After the installation of these extensions, if we select a line and right-click, it does some actions such as formatting by default. and the pop-up menu disappears as soon as the right-click button is released.

I looked in the extension settings and they do not have an option to stop it from changing these basic settings.

This is really annoying, for example when I have to select and copy a line. I could select a line, right-click the mouse and click on copy. If these extensions are installed all these behaviours are altered so much so that it is so difficult to use the editor even for basic things. +

Is there any way to use these extensions, without having to suffer these annoying changes? To be precise, to install and use these extensions by preserving the basic mouse right-click action and behaviour?

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/ckv9ks/remove_items_from_right_click_context_menu/

Comment: try to find the extension causing this effect, disable all "format" settings, run with all extensions disabled to see if it goes away, run with all settings removed at all levels (User/Workspace/Folder). I do not have this behavior and I also use PyLance as language server

Comment: I already know which extension it is causing, it is caused by pylance.